# select/deselect single element in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm trying to make an option list with `v-for`, where you can choose only one option at a time. It works great except I can't unselect the option.

```html
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li 
        v-for="l in list" 
        id="l.key"
        @click="selectone(l.key, l.isSelected)"
        v-bind:class="{ selected : l.isSelected, notselected : !l.isSelected }"
        > {{ l.tec }} </li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

**The JS**

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#main",
  data: {
    list: [
      {key:"0", tec:"html", isSelected:false},
      {key:"1", tec:"css", isSelected:false},
      {key:"2", tec:"JS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"3", tec:"Git", isSelected:false},
      {key:"4", tec:"NodeJS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"5", tec:"Postgres", isSelected:false}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    selectone: function(k, o) {
      for( i = 0; i < this.list.length; i ++ ) {
        if(this.list[i].isSelected == true ) {
          this.list[i].isSelected = false
        }
      }
      this.list[k].isSelected = !this.list[k].isSelected;
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```css
.selected {
    background:lightpink;
}
.notselected {
    background:lightblue;
}
```

Shouldn't my loop deactivate all options every time I click an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `selectone()`, you're setting `isSelected=false` for *all* list items, and then *attempting* to toggle the selected list item's `isSelected`, which was just previously set to `false` (i.e., the "toggle" would always set `isSelected=true` for the selected item).

The loop should exclude the key of the selected item:

```js
selectone(key) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
    if (this.list[i].key !== key) {
       this.list[i].isSelected = false
    }
  }

  // this.toggleSelection(key)
}
```

But the toggling code itself needs a bug-fix to properly lookup the list item. The first argument to `selectone()` is the `key` property of the list item. In order to get the item by key from the `list` array, you have to search the `list`, e.g., using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
toggleSelection(key) {
  const listItem = this.list.find(item => item.key === key)
  if (listItem) {
    listItem.isSelected = !listItem.isSelected
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [
      {key:"0", tec:"html", isSelected:false},
      {key:"1", tec:"css", isSelected:false},
      {key:"2", tec:"JS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"3", tec:"Git", isSelected:false},
      {key:"4", tec:"NodeJS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"5", tec:"Postgres", isSelected:false}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    selectone(key) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
        if (this.list[i].key !== key) {
          this.list[i].isSelected = false
        }
      }

      this.toggleSelection(key)
    },
    toggleSelection(key) {
      const listItem = this.list.find(item => item.key === key)
      if (listItem) {
        listItem.isSelected = !listItem.isSelected
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background:lightpink;
}
.notselected {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li 
        v-for="l in list" 
        id="l.key"
        @click="selectone(l.key, l.isSelected)"
        v-bind:class="{ selected : l.isSelected, notselected : !l.isSelected }"
        > {{ l.tec }} </li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could track the selected index, set it in the item's `click`-handler, and set the `class` binding based on the item's index matching the selected index:

```html
// template
<li 
  v-for="(l, index) in list" 
  id="l.key"
  @click="selectedIndex = index"
  v-bind:class="{ selected: index === selectedIndex, notselected: index !== selectedIndex }"
  > {{ l.tec }} </li>

// script
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: -1,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedIndex: -1,
    list: [
      {key:"0", tec:"html", isSelected:false},
      {key:"1", tec:"css", isSelected:false},
      {key:"2", tec:"JS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"3", tec:"Git", isSelected:false},
      {key:"4", tec:"NodeJS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"5", tec:"Postgres", isSelected:false}
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background:lightpink;
}
.notselected {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li 
        v-for="(l, index) in list" 
        id="l.key"
        @click="selectedIndex = index"
        v-bind:class="{ selected : index === selectedIndex, notselected : index !== selectedIndex }"
        > {{ l.tec }} </li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your close. try this: (un tested)

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li 
        v-for="(l,index) in list" 
        id="l.key"
        @click="selectone(l, index)"
        v-bind:class="{ selected : l.isSelected, notselected : !l.isSelected }"
        > {{ l.tec }} </li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
new Vue({
  el:"#main",
  data: {
    list: [
      {key:"0", tec:"html", isSelected:false},
      {key:"1", tec:"css", isSelected:false},
      {key:"2", tec:"JS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"3", tec:"Git", isSelected:false},
      {key:"4", tec:"NodeJS", isSelected:false},
      {key:"5", tec:"Postgres", isSelected:false}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    selectone:function(l, index){

      for( i = 0; i < this.list.length; i ++ ) {
        this.list[i].isSelected = false
        }
      l.isSelected = true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

to explain you were miss using the variable k in your function. that should be the entire object not the index